# Folder in directory not showing up in local server html

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, server

I'm running a local server on my computer through a chrome extension. This is the directory it points to:

[image]

Inside my `css` folder, I have another `img` folder:

[image]

When I use the chrome extension to start a server, and inspect it with chrome developer tools, I don't see the `img` folder?

[image]

I'm new to web servers so I'm not sure why this is happening and why it doesn't detect it? Why web server points to `web` folder. Since it doesn't happen none of my images inside load?

Comment: Have you contacted the author of the extension? Can you share link to documentation of extension? Have any issues been filed at extension repository concerning directories within directories not being accessible?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

Comment: It has pretty favourable reviews so I'm not sure what the issue is

Comment: Have you browsed open issues https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome/issues/62, https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome/issues/83 Or considered filing an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that maybe the server only serves the sources that are used. Try using an img from the img dir and see if it appears.

Comment: Only when a resource is used by the web page, does it get loaded +1

Comment: yea that's what I was thinking I'm pretty sure thats why its not in the sources view in dev tools

Answer (score 0):

AdBlock for Chrome may cause images to be blocked based on image dimensions.

If you are using this extension, try disabling it.